# Laplace Transform conundrum

Tags: laplace-transform

consider,
x1(t) + constant = x2(t)  => w/ laplace, X1(s) + c/s = X2(s)
but, take the time derivative of the first equation,
x1dot = x2dot => sX1(s) = sX2(s) => X1(s) = X2(s).

Which is correct?

Comment: Quite hard to read, I strongly recommend you to use mathjax for your math symbols. [Click here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

When you have taken the transform of the differentiated equation, you have missed off constant terms. For the transform of the derivative is 
$$sX(s)-x(0)$$
You should find that the relation between you 2 functions then causes the original constant to be present, as one should expect.